# Error while loading rule 'prettier/prettier': context.getPhysicalFilename is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I am learning react js. I am a very beginner at this topic. But when I am doing setup to create a react environment I got an error. I have tried to solve the problem by [Charles Stover blog in medium](https://charles-stover.medium.com/resolving-prettier-react-context-getphysicalfilename-is-not-a-function-52a250f68291). But I got an error `Command "up" not found`.

Here's my index.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
ReactDOM.render(
   <React.StrictMode>
      <App />
   </React.StrictMode>,
document.getElementById('root')
);
reportWebVitals();
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "myreact",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "lint": "yarn add -D prettier && yarn add -D babel-eslint && npx install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb && yarn add -D eslint-config-prettier eslint-plugin-prettier"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "7.2.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "18.2.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.4.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.21.5",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "1.7.0",
    "prettier": "^2.3.2"
  }
}
```

When I am running `yarn start` in terminal, I am getting an error.

```
Error while loading rule 'prettier/prettier': context.getPhysicalFilename is not a function
Occurred while linting F:\react-projects\myreact\src\index.js
```

Now what should I do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got two different solution.

1. remove

```
"prettier/prettier": [
            "error",
            {
                "trailingComma": "es5",
                "singleQuote": true,
                "printWidth": 100,
                "tabWidth": 4,
                "semi": true,
                "endOfLine": "auto"
            }
        ]
```

from `.eslintrc` folder and change react script version from 4.0.3 to 4.0.1 and run `npm install`.

2. Use `yarn upgrade -R eslint` and change react script version from 4.0.3 to 4.0.1 and run `npm install`.

Comment: my current version "eslint": "^6.8.0", but i got same problem then not solve and i use vue and react and nodejs the error has on trigger when use 'plugin:prettier/recommended' on extends: [ ] script

Comment: solved by extends: [
    // 'plugin:vue/recommended', // comment this
    // '@vue/airbnb', // comment this
    'plugin:prettier/recommended'
  ],

Answer (score 3):

**Upgrade eslint**

I had the same error with Next.js:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "with-eslint",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "type-check": "tsc"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "install": "0.13.0",
    "next": "12.0.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "12.12.21",
    "@types/react": "17.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "eslint": "7.24.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.7",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.5.1",
    "typescript": "4.5.4"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "printWidth": 80,
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": true
  }
}
```

.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "next", "prettier"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error"
  }
}
```

pages/index.tsx

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
  let n: number
  let s = 'abc'
  s = "abc"
  let unused
  if (false) {
    React.useEffect(() => 1)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <script src="https://fake-script.com" />
      <p>Home</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

and moving to:

```
    "eslint": "8.5.0",
```

solved it.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated react-scripts to `4.0.1` and eslint to `7.32.0`. It worked.